# pandas: set cell value to index of current row?

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
   a    b   c    country
0  5    7   11   Morocco
1  5    9   9    Nigeria
2  6    2   13   Spain
```

I would like to add a row `d`, which has the country name plus the index of the row (plus 1). Like this:

```
   a    b   c    country    d
0  5    7   11   Morocco    1. Morocco
1  5    9   9    Nigeria    2. Nigeria
2  6    2   13   Spain      3. Spain
```

How can I do this? I can do:

```
df['d'] = '1. ' + df['country']
```

But I'm having difficulty working out how to get the index of the row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert index values to strings and add column `country`:

```
df['d'] = (df.index + 1).astype(str) + '. ' + df['country']
print (df)
   a  b   c  country           d
0  5  7  11  Morocco  1. Morocco
1  5  9   9  Nigeria  2. Nigeria
2  6  2  13    Spain    3. Spain
```

Another solution for `python 3.6+`:

```
df['d'] = [f'{i + 1}. {x}' for i, x in enumerate(df['country'])]
#for versions below
#df['d'] = ['{}. {}'.format(i + 1, x) for i, x in enumerate(df['country'])]
print (df)
   a  b   c  country           d
0  5  7  11  Morocco  1. Morocco
1  5  9   9  Nigeria  2. Nigeria
2  6  2  13    Spain    3. Spain
```

Comment: hi @jezrael, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50903622/how-to-extract-non-na-values-in-a-list-or-dict-from-a-pandas-dataframe