# How to extract non NA values in a list or dict from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a df like this,

df,

```
    AAA BBB CCC
0   4   10  100
1   5   20  50
2   6   30  -30
3   7   40  -50
```

`df_mask = pd.DataFrame({'AAA' : [True] * 4, 'BBB' : [False] * 4,'CCC' : [True,False] * 2})`
and `df.where(df_mask)` is

```
    AAA BBB CCC
0   4   NaN 100.0
1   5   NaN NaN
2   6   NaN -30.0
3   7   NaN NaN
```

I am trying to extract the non null values like this.

I tried,
     `df[df.where(df_mask).notnull()].to_dict()` but it gives all the values

My expected output is,

```
{'AAA': {0: 4, 1: 5, 2: 6, 3: 7},
 'CCC': {0: 100.0, 2: -30.0}}
```

Comment: Good example no how to ask a question. Upvoted!

Comment: Yeah, thanks. It's been a while since I last saw a decent question here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use `agg` here:

```
v = df.where(df_mask).agg(lambda x: x.dropna().to_dict())
```

On older versions, `apply` does the same thing (albeit a bit slower).

```
v = df.where(df_mask).apply(lambda x: x.dropna().to_dict())
```

And now, filter out rows with empty dictionaries for the final step:

```
res = v[v.str.len() > 0].to_dict()
```

```
print(res)
{'AAA': {0: 4.0, 1: 5.0, 2: 6.0, 3: 7.0}, 'CCC': {0: 100.0, 2: -30.0}}
```

---

Another apply-free option is a dict-comprehension:

```
v = df.where(df_mask)  
res = {k : v[k].dropna().to_dict() for k in df} 

print(res)
{'AAA': {0: 4, 1: 5, 2: 6, 3: 7}, 'BBB': {}, 'CCC': {0: 100.0, 2: -30.0}}
```

Note that this (slightly) simpler solution retains keys with empty values.

Comment: @pyd replace `agg` with `apply` for the same effect. I don't recommend apply because it's slower than agg but on older versions I suppose you have no choice.

Comment: how to convert it to list instead of dict.. like `{'AAA':[4,5,6,7],'CCC':[100,-30]}`

Comment: I tried the same, not working. I will try something else and update

Comment: @pyd no need. Try this: `res = {k : v[k].dropna().tolist() for k in df}` and then just filter out empty values as needed.

Comment: @pyd It's `v = df.where(df_mask); res = {k : v[k].dropna().tolist() for k in df}`

Comment: Thanks, its working. I was giving 'to_list' instead 'tolist', sorry

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate `df`'s columns and apply `dropna` `Series`wise

```
{col: df[col].dropna().values for col in df}
```

Which yields

```
{'AAA': array([4, 5, 6, 7]),
 'BBB': array([], dtype=float64),
 'CCC': array([ 100.,  -30.])}
```

You can filter out empty arrays such as `'BBB'` with

```
{key: val for key, val in ddict.items() if val}
```